# Netezza Jar not working with source jdbc connector in confluent

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, netezza, apache-kafka-connect

I'm facing issue while connecting Zetezza database from confluent source jdbc connector.
source-jdbc connector properties:

```
name=source-netezza
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1    
connection.url=jdbc:netezza://10.245.*.*:5480/DATABASE=mydb,user=admin,password=password
table.whitelist=netezza_str
mode=bulk
topic.prefix=netezza_str_
```

After executing the command I'm getting below errors

```
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:netezza://10.245.*.*:5480/mydb,user=admin,password=password for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:netezza://10.245.*.*:5480/mydb,user=admin,password=password
```

I've tried with netezza-3.2.2 jar and nzjdbc jar.

Comment: Is the JDBC driver on your `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: Are you actually executing it with an IP address containing '*' ? 10.245.*.* seems invalid to me, but since that is not obvious in the the error message I may be one step ahead of you on this ?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt yes. It is working fine with TeraData as well as mysql jdbc driver where I can see records corresponding topics.